# How to solve Missing Method in UserController using Cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am getting missing method in UsersController error.

> The action table_datatable.ctp is not defined in UsersController.
>
> Error: Create UsersController::table_datatable.ctp() in file: src\Controller\UsersController.php.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function table_datatable.ctp()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message depends on the requested url, that error message means you're requesting this url:

```
http://example.com/users/table_datatable.ctp
```

`.ctp` is *never* in the url - urls do not match the path to template files; only [the webroot folder](https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/webroot) is designed to be directly web-accessible.

Before continuing it would be a good idea to do [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html), it only takes about 15 minutes and will give you a basic introduction as to how CakePHP works, and how to use it.